# Making content_for work with Slim

Tags: ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

I'm working on implementing content_for and yield_content support in [Hardwired](http://hardwiredcms.com).

The Sinatra::Contrib implementation doesn't work, so I tried a simpler version:

```
  module ContentFor

    def content_for(key, &block)
      content_blocks[key.to_sym] << block.call
      return ""
    end

    def content_for?(key)
      content_blocks[key.to_sym].any?
    end

    def yield_content(key, *args)
      content_blocks[key.to_sym].join
    end

    private

    def content_blocks
      @content_blocks ||= Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately, this repeats content (content_for seems to grab everything in the template, not just child content).

What approach should I take to implementing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Slim only captures child content if you use `=` or `==`, not `-`.

Just use `= content_for :area do` instead of `- content_for :area do`

Note: Apparently this issue is specific to the Sinatra-style `content_for` and `yield_content`. Apparently the more sophisticated Rails implementation manages to use buffer magic to make this possible with `-` as well.

Comment: Your general statement is not true . I am using slim templates with - content_for all the time.

Comment: Sinatra or Rails content_for? Which branch of Slim?

Comment: Rails 3.2 and Slim 1.3.6. I see the original question deals with Sinatra, but I found your statement a bit misleading.

Comment: I've added a clarification comment.